# Display Kinect Accelerometer data continously in Windows Form Label

Tags: c#, windows, forms, kinect, kinect-sdk

I am relatively new to Kinect programming.

I am working in Windows Forms.

I am able to access the Kinect accelerometer sensor data at any ONE point of time, using debug mode.

How do i get the data continuously and keep updating a label in Form continuously without any prompt from user?

I tried using while(true) and timer, but didnt work.

I also tried the KinectSensor.KinectSensors.StatusChanged event but the Microsoft site states that The Kinect SDK does NOT provide a change notification event for the accelerometer.

Thanks

Comment: I had the same problem, you might find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19349312/kinect-accelerometer-data-timer-backup

Answer (score 0):

The timer approach actually worked, with a 10 Millisecond trigger time.